# How i create onclick button in my google map api web

Tags: javascript

[**my image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpNNc.png)

Guys please click "my image" for details. I want when i click the test button, the triangle will appear on the map, here are my .js and .html. Does anyone know the problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Move the function abc() out of the initmap() function, they are 2 separate functions

Comment: Thank you. But i have done that but it still didn't work